# Integer solutions (star and bar)

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=10$.
How many **non-negative** integer solutions if $x_1 > x_2$?

Apparently counting $x_1$ and $x_2$ one by one is too slow, and impractical if the sum is not 10 but 100 instead. Is there a general way to solve this kind of problems?

Comment: There are infinitely many *non-integer* solutions. You probably mean *integer* solutions. In that case, you may rewrite equation as $x_1'+2x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 = 9$.

Comment: **non-integer** solutions are $\infty^5$ . Are you looking for **integral** or **non integral** solutions ? and maybe for **integral non-negative**?

Comment: @Abstraction I'm sorry for the typo. I meant non-negative integers :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. By [Stars-and-Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), the number of non-negative integer solutions of
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=10$$
is $\binom{10+(5-1)}{5-1}$.
The numbers of non-negative integer solutions of
$$k+k+x_3+x_4+x_5=10$$
that is
$$x_3+x_4+x_5=10-2k$$
for $k=0,1,\dots ,5$ is $\binom{10-2k+(3-1)}{3-1}$.
Can you take it from here?

Finally you should find that the number you are looking for is $420$.

Comment: That means by finding out $\binom{14}{4}$ first, and subtract by the number of solutions for $x_3+x_4+x_5=10-2k$, since if two integers have different values it must mean that one of them is larger than the other. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @Lon Edwards Yes. Then after the subtraction you have to divide the result by two. In one half $x_1>x_2$, in the other one $x_2>x_1$.